# How to work with jpegcrop in Windows?

Tags: windows, images

I have just learned about, and downloaded `jpegcrop` from http://jpegclub.org/ - which should apparently allow lossless cropping from JPEG images.

So I loaded this picture https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Crab_spider_%28Misumena_Vatia%29_with_prey_silver-spotted_skipper_%28Hesperia_comma%29.jpg in the program:

[image: jpegcrop]

... and just clicked on Save Frame As ... and saved as "crab_cut.jpg".

But when I open this image in Windows, I get "Sorry. Photos can't open this file, because the format is currently unsupported, or the file is corrupted":

[image: windows photos]

However, "crab_cut.jpg" does open fine in Gimp.

So I was wondering - can I somehow make a lossless crop of a .jpg image in `jpegcrop`, so that the resulting image is readable everywhere, including Windows Photos?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue just now, and solved it by selecting Huffman (default or optimized) as "Entropy Coding Method" in the app preferences.

Comment: Indeed: [the documentation page for JpegCrop's options window](https://jpegclub.org/jpegcrop/) does warn that Arithmetic entropy encoding does not have wide support: "CAUTION: arithmetic coded JPEG is not yet widely implemented, so many decoders will be unable to view an arithmetic coded JPEG file at all." - but for some crazy reason JpegCrop has Arithmetic encoding selected by default, argh.

Comment: @GFK: Is there a way to set "Huffman optimized" as default.

Comment: @Dai Arithmetic encoding is (generally) the most efficient one (in terms of file-size), I would rather ask the other way round: Why exist JPEG-Viewers that are unable to open valid JPEG , I think such viewers should be banned that efficient encodings get more common.

Answer (score 1):

The Irfanview freeware is offering lossless crops as well.